# CSS for mail doesn't apply?

Tags: html, css, email, apply

I have no idea what's going on now. I threw together a simple page with very simple CSS. I used tables cause i know you can't use div elements like normal for emails. So after viewing it in my browser, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FBtf.png

And after sending it through mail (the cells data has been replaced):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuXvA.png

So the CSS doesn't apply at all!

Here's the HTML and CSS:

http://pastebin.com/PySeeW4m

Any ideas?

Comment: How is it being sent? What are you testing it on?

Comment: Yes, you *can* use `<div>` elements in an email.

Comment: Different email clients (even the http-based ones like hotmail) handle messages differently. It could be it works fine in other clients. Your client could be stripping out css as "not allowed". How many have you tested it in?

Comment: For e-mails, I really recommend that you use in-line style. It's ugly, hard to read and to maintain, but have better support. But I don't see any problems in using divs.

Comment: I'm sending it through PHP, and i've only tested it on gmail. I'll try inline styling instead, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most e-mail clients only read the CSS if it is provided inline through `style=` tags, Mailchimp provides a great tool to do this automatically:

[CSS Inliner Tool](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css)

Comment: Yep, that did it, thanks! Great tool as well, bookmarked. (I would mark your answer as accepted but stackoverflow is being a dick right now!)

Answer (score 2):

CSS in e-mail is only partially supported and support differs greatly amongst clients. Have a look at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
You probably need to have all CSS inline for more compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

please consider that f.i. gmail strips out style definitions from the HTML template.
You can use  a workaround and include style information direct in the element like this

```
<div style="width:150px">...</div>
```

To use your css like it is right now just use a css parser and attach it to the elements via a regular expression

Regards